# No such file or directory: 'geckodriver' for a simple Selenium application in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running a simple example of selenium on Linux:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("something")
```

and get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'
```

How to fix it?

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:46:01) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160602] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>>
```

Comment: In Java I would neet to set the system property of the gecko driver, might be what you need to do as well, but I don't know Python that well. What I use in Java: `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/driver");`

Answer (score 55):

**Downloading geckodriver**

The geckodriver executable can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/docs/source/index.rst).

**Python3 venv**

Download the geckodriver executable from the above link and extract it to `env/bin/` to make it accessible to only the virtual environment.

In your python code, you will now be able to do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

**Linux**

If you would like to make it available system wide, download the geckodriver executable from the above link and extract it to `/usr/bin/` (or anything inside of your $PATH)

**Windows**

*Note: this needs a windows user to test and confirm*

Download geckodriver from the above link and extract it to `C:\Windows\System32\` (or anything inside your Path environment variable).

**Mac OS X**

*Note: I took this from [Vincent van Leeuwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569215/vincent-van-leeuwen)'s answer [in this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607709/1402441). Putting it here for the sake of lumping everything in one answer*

To make geckodriver available system wide, open up your Terminal App and perform the following command:

`brew install geckodriver`

**More Info**

More info on selenium can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/docs/source/index.rst):

> Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox, for example, requires geckodriver, which needs to be installed before the below examples can be run. Make sure it's in your PATH, e. g., place it in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.
>
> Failure to observe this step will give you an error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the info in case the link(s) go down?

Comment: @Suspended could you clarify what you downloaded?  I was able to download both Windows and Linux binaries from the link in the answer

Answer (score 10):

I faced same issue in Linux. I used below steps to fix that Error.

```
cd /bin

# Check on https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases for the latest release
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux32.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux32.tar.gz
rm geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux32.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
export PATH=$PATH:/bin/geckodriver

geckodriver --version
```

Note : I tried with latest version geckodriver-v0.26.0 but it not working for me, That's Why I installed the old version v0.24.0

Answer (score 9):

Linux:
You can install "sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver"

Comment: Is the package no longer there for Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: It is sadly not there for me either @Velkan.

Comment: 22.04 is out, but they aren't undeleting my question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401374/firefox-geckodriver-is-now-missing-in-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 6):

Selenium requires geckodriver to interface with Firefox. Here's how to install geckodriver:

1. Download geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz (or if you need the 32 bit version, go to https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases to see more download options)
2. Extract the file into your Downloads folder
3. Open a console and run `sudo mv ~/Downloads/geckodriver /usr/bin`

Answer (score 2):

#### Mac OSX:

Firefox?
`brew install geckodriver`

Chrome?
`brew install chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

On linux, you can [install Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) and then `brew install geckodriver` through it

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew install geckodriver
```

or by [installing Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/download.html)

```
curl https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh
nix install geckodriver
```

but adding another package manager to your system might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mac OSX:

Firefox?
`brew install geckodriver`

Chrome?
`brew install chromedriver`

#### Choose one:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()   # brew install geckodriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()    # brew install chromedriver
```

Comment: Started editing their answer and decided it was better to just add my own instead of editing theirs multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way:

```
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

You do not need manual installations.

Comment: Does not help using latest Debian/Ubuntu: E: Unable to locate package firefox-geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package that autoinstalls it crossplattform, no need for users to manually install it: https://pypi.org/project/geckodriver-autoinstaller/