# How do I install Geckodriver?

Tags: python, selenium, path, webautomation, geckodriver

I am attempting to work with `Selenium` in Python. However, I do not know what to do given the below from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

`Selenium` requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox, for example, requires `geckodriver`, which needs to be installed before the below examples can be run. Make sure it’s in your PATH, e.g., place it in `/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin`.

I am running windows 7 32bit. I found geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I have mostly used the Anaconda distribution of Python to work with excel so I do not know what is a "PATH"

Thanks,

**UPDATE**:

I updated the PATH as shown in the comments. Here is the full error traceback.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\user1>python
>
> Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1
>   900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
> ```
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site
>   -packages\selenium-2.53.6-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", li
>   ne 80, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout)
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site
>   -packages\selenium-2.53.6-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connect
>   ion.py", line 52, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site
>   -packages\selenium-2.53.6-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py
>   ", line 67, in launch_browser
>       self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site
>   -packages\selenium-2.53.6-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py
>   ", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
>       env=self._firefox_env)
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subp
>   rocess.py", line 947, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subp
>   rocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: this link may help you to solve this problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/851401/where-to-find-geckodriver-needed-by-selenium-python-package#new-answer

Answer (score 38):

1. You can download the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
2. unzip it
3. Copy that .exe file and put your into python parent folder (e.g., `C:\Python34`)
4. write your scripts.

It will execute successfully.

Answer (score 18):

There is an easy way to install Geckodriver:

1. Install `webdrivermanager` with `pip`

   `pip install webdrivermanager`
2. Install the driver for Firefox and Chrome

   `webdrivermanager firefox chrome --linkpath /usr/local/bin`
3. Or install the driver only for Firefox

   `webdrivermanager firefox --linkpath /usr/local/bin`
4. Or install the driver only for Chrome

   `webdrivermanager chrome --linkpath /usr/local/bin`

Comment: when importing `from webdrivermanager import GeckoDriverManager`, who to get the executable path programmatically?

Comment: This works on Debian 10 and firefox 98.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way if you are on windows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'[Your path]\geckodriver.exe')
```

Example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: I added it to the PATH, and as Admin I shared the folder with the user, in fact with me, one upvote.

Comment: `service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER")
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)` this is due to changes in selenium 4.10.0, as Michael Mintz said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802588/python-selenium-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-path#:~:text=TypeError%3A%20WebDriver.__init__%20%28%29%20got%20an%20unexpected%20keyword%20argument,s%20%3D%20Service%20%28r%27D%3Apathtogeckodriver.exe%27%29%20browser%20%3D%20Firefox%20%28service%3Ds%29

Answer (score 6):

**For Linux/Ubuntu:**

The following simple installation worked for me:

```
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

No additional driver installation was required.

Reference: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/5282#issuecomment-666283451

**For windows:**

Follow the instructions here: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-install-geckodriver-Python-windows.php

Comment: there is not apt on windows 7

Comment: @Cesar this seems to be promising: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-install-geckodriver-Python-windows.php (didn't try it myself, I am on a Linux distro).

Comment: I understand, but the user asked for windows 7 ^_^
this works well actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61084589/320926

Comment: You should get geckodriver directly from the Mozilla releases on github: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0

Comment: When using Ubuntu 22.04, this brings up the error message: "'firefox-geckodriver' has no installation candidate".

Answer (score 3):

If you're on macOS/Apple, you can use Homebrew:
`brew install geckodriver`

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40314803/1145905)

Answer (score 2):

Some options, choose 1:

- Move the exe file to a folder in your `PATH` environment variable.
- Update `PATH` to have the directory that contains the exe.
- Explicitly override `os.environ["webdriver.gecko.driver"]`

basically drag and drop the geckodriver someplace where you have your executables, you should then be able to open the command line and use it.

`/bin` on linux, and `C:\Program Files`

see:

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2672
- https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-windows-program-files-folder-where-do-things-g

specifically the explanations on how the driver is seen, 
where it can be put ,and how to modify the way selenium finds it.

Comment: Okay - I added the geckodriver into the PATH via environment variables. C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\User1\Documents\Python Scripts\Python Modules\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe

Comment: running from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox() resulted in a new error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified @jmunsch

Comment: cgoldberg: `PATH environment variable contains a list of directories to scan. You have added a path containing a filename, not a directory.`

Comment: @polonius11 almost there

Comment: What should I be changing? C:\Users\User‌​1\Documents\Python Scripts\Python Modules\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe .... this path has the geckodriver.exe file name? ..... @jmunsch ? I haven't worked with directories before.

Comment: @polonius11 instead of filename, use the directory: `C:\Us....\some_folder`

Comment: @polonius11 `some_folder` is the folder which contains the exe ... do not include the filename. the environment `PATH`  is a list of directories, not a list of filenames ... should be `C:\Users\User‌​1\Documents\Python Scripts\Python Modules\geckodriver`

Comment: I made the change but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I updated the question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked (Windows 10, Firefox browser):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\......YOUR_PATH.......\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://EXAMPLE_URL.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile for Win10 you can simply use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

This will download the geckodrive prior to its first use and store it at the appropriate location. No need to set any paths explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 - Selenium plus webdriver for Firefox;

1. Open up Command line
2. Enter **Pip install -U Selenium**   (The -U will upgrade it to the latest Selenium version.)
   [This example selenium is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvBuv.png)
3. Go to https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
4. At the time of writing I chose the latest version which was simply the version listed at the top of the page. For me it was v0.24.0.
5. Scroll down to assets and then click and download the correct driver. For windows it will be a zip file. Most likely 64bit. 
   [Download the webdriver by clicking on the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuunN.png)
   5.Right click on the downloaded file and unzip the file.
6. Copy and paste the file to somewhere in your python directory. e.g. If I installed Python in C:\Python\Python37 I would paste the file in there so gecko would be located in C:\Python\Python37\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64

[Copying the file path of the geckodriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUf4f.png)

7. Inside that folder you just copied will be the geckodriver.exe
8. In Windows 10, click the "windows" button and search "environment variables" 
   [Find environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByfpO.png)
   OR find it using these instructions; https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm
9. Click on the "environment variables" box at the bottom right hand corner.
10. In the bottom box "System Variables" highlight the "Path" variable like so
    [Adding environment variable Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYSXf.png)
11. Press edit and then add the entry at the bottom of the list. Copy and paste the location where the geckodriver.exe file lives. For me it was C:\Python\Python37\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64 (or where you copied the file in step 6)
    [Adding gecko to the windows PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKC3f.png)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid links becoming out of date, please refer the soource.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver
follow the readme instructions to the "Downloads" > "Releases" link.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

First pip install selenium and webdriver-manager.

This code will install the latest driver and cache it. It will also use a Service object to load the webdriver, which is important because executable_path is deprecated.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).