# 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, path, geckodriver

Mac OS user here. I'm trying to run a command in my python IDLE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I've ran `brew install geckodriver`, and `which geckodriver` returns `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver` so I'm sure it's installed correctly. It seems like it's still not running properly however?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61084589/7508077

Answer (score 10):

Your error message is quite clear:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'
```

You have to set the path to the **geckodriver**. There are different ways to do that.

You could set the path to the geckodriver in the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/.../path2Your/geckodriver')
```

or insert the path to the geckodriver in the **PATH** environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/.../path2Your/geckodriver
```

I never tried to move the executable in the `/usr/local/bin/` in a mac os. I tried in an ubuntu os and it works. I think should be fine.

Probably it's because the file is not executable. If it isn't, go to `/usr/local/bin/` and make it executable:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

Comment: Thank you. the executable path option is working fine in my case

Answer (score 6):

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and had the same issue here.

In my case, this works fine. Hope that works for you!

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the things that best worked for me is just copy the executable geckodriver file.

Go into the bin folder:

If your on linux you can find it in the below location:

```
/home/user_name/.local/bin
```

Paste your geckodriver exe here.

So your final code should be like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'geckodriver')
```

This worked for me like charm but am not sure whether it is the right way.