# Python Selenium: 'unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I just started using `selenium` with Python and I keep getting the following error code:

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Here's the code for the context:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://example'
driver_path = r"D:\path\to\geckodriver.exe"

browser = Firefox(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get(url)
```

Thanks in advance!

I checked the path, the version of the `selenium` package and made sure that I have the right `geckodriver.exe` but still get the error.

Comment: What version of selenium do you have?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in my earlier solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550727/7058266, this is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `executable_path` was removed.

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER")
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

But you no longer need to specify an `executable_path` due to a fully operational Selenium Manager in `4.10.0`, so this is all you need:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use that :

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
url = 'https://example'
browser = Firefox()
browser.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

[*executable_path*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/7429447) which was deprecated earlier is now completely removed from [***selenium-4.10.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-4.10.0) through the merge [Remove deprecated code in driver classes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12030).

[image: executable_path]

---

### Details

If you look at the [constructor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22fL39) after *`self`*, the next argument is *`options`* followed by *`service`*.

So when you mention:

```
browser = Firefox(executable_path=driver_path)
```

Python interpreter doesn't recognizes the keyword `executable_path` anymore and raises

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

---

### Solution

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you have to use the keyword [*`Service()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447). So you need to change as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

s = Service(r'D:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
browser = Firefox(service=s)
```

---

Incase you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use the *`Service()`* either as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

browser = Firefox()
```

Answer (score 0):

those who are using Robot Framework(python) use can use code as below

```
Create Webdriver   Chrome Service(your driver location)
```

works for me!

Answer (score -1):

`unexpected keyword argument` means exactly that, you're trying to pass a keyword argument or named argument to a function that does not have that argument defined.

Remember there are 2 types of arguments in python, based on how you supply them to a function, keyword/named and positional.

```py
def greet(name, age):
    return f"Hello, {name}! You are {age} years old."


# Using positional arguments, where order matters
result = greet("Leo", 30)
print(result)  # Output: Hello, Leo! You are 30 years old.
result = greet(30, "Leo")
print(result)  # Output: Hello, 30! You are Leo years old.
# Using keyword/named arguments, where order does not matter (unless you're mixing positional and keyword, then positionals go first, always)
result = greet(age=30, name="Leo")
print(result)  # Output: Hello, Leo! You are 30 years old.
```

Check the documentation for your version of selenium and check if, for the Firefox class, the init has an argument called `executable_path`.