# Selenium Python firefox webdriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, proxy, selenium-webdriver-python

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);

profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");

profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox_profile=profile);

I am using below code to config but it's giving an error. You should need to be include executive path. How can I solve it. I am Running this code in pycharm.

[You can also see the image for more brief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUOFU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path.

1. Try this out [option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302006/no-such-file-or-directory-geckodriver-for-a-python-simple-selenium-applicatio/56837661)
2. option 2

```
from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/path/to/geckodriver')
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Yeah I know this solution but I am doing it with proxy. do you know how to open a url using proxy.
thanks.

Comment: But form the image you have posted, it seems gecko driver path is not specified. That is why you are getting `FileNotFoundError`. I believe this has nothing to do with the proxy.