# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver' using Selenium libary in Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory, geckodriver, filenotfounderror

I am trying to use Selenium in Google Colab, but i get some errors when i try to run a Firefox instance.
i followed this links:

- [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/) here, i tried with the Driver Management Software but i got the error that says that was unable to find the binary location to Firefox, so i follow this other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000401/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/66000618#66000618) , but i was unable to make it run

So i tried with the Hard Coded Location, but I got the error:

```
Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I actually downloaded the geckodrive and follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302006/no-such-file-or-directory-geckodriver-for-a-simple-selenium-application-in-py)

I've uploaded the grecodriver to my Drive and access with the google.colab library, but i always got the error:

```
No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver'
```

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

service = FirefoxService(executable_path= '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

[image: My drive´s files]

The entire error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stdin=PIPE,
---> 76                                             creationflags=self.creationflags)
     77         except TypeError:

4 frames

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: `geckodriver.exe` is a file and not a folder, right? Try replacing the `geckodriver` in `service = FirefoxService(executable_path= '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver')` to `geckodriver.exe` to make the line: `service = FirefoxService(executable_path= '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver.exe')`. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder it is a file, and it is not necessary put '.exe', even so i tried and give error that says that geckodriver dont have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Santillana/geckodriver'
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) executable.

---

### Analysis

As per the error message it seems you are on a [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) system. However you have downloaded the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) version of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453):

[image: downloaded]

---

### Solution

Instead of the *Windows* version of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220) possibly you need to download the *Linux* version of *GeckoDriver* executable.

Comment: i tried with the linux version but i get the error: ``` Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line ``` the same that i got when i try with the Driver Management Software driver installation, so i suppose that i must have some firefox installation in my colab?, but i don't think is correct

Comment: That's even a better error, atleast we are using the correct version of GeckoDriver. Shouldn't _`Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location`_ be a different question all together?